# How to get D3.js's tidy tree graph from reducing the lateral distance of siblings as depth increases

Tags: javascript, graph, svg, d3.js

The problem I am having comes down to the way the Reingold-Tilford tree reduces the separation between siblings as their depth increases. This causes overlap if the nodes and text are not scaled in relation to their depth:
[image]

This may be a better example:
[image]

Notice how the separation between siblings is decreasing. I am confident that his has a purpose in keeping the graphs tighter, but I am okay with it consuming more space.

I have gone through the source code for the layout.tree and cannot find where the code defines that the distances will reduce. I am able to increase the distance of all the nodes at all depths, but this is also not exactly the point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/13032722/173225 help?

Comment: Is it! (Yes, yes it is.) Thank you. Post this suggestion below and I will upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple solutions in this question: [D3 tree vertical separation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032722/d3-tree-vertical-separation).

It looks as though https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/317 (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/commit/47d7cade203f4f2d066c898a7fe3461b1ca3a06e) may have a fix in the D3 source.