# d3 tree layout - force child nodes to use available space

Tags: javascript, tree, d3.js, visualization

I have a tree-based layout using d3, based on the collapsable tree layout example [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html).

As you can see in the demo, the vertical spacing between nodes is constant for each level in the tree, meaning nodes can bunch together while leaving a lot of white space.

Instead, I'd like each level to take up all the vertical space available. For example, a level with 2 child nodes would have nodes spaced at 0% and 100%, while 3 child nodes would be spaced at 0%, 50% and 100%.

Hopefully this is possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find some helpful information in [How to get D3.js's tidy tree graph from reducing the lateral distance of siblings as depth increases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177350/how-to-get-d3-jss-tidy-tree-graph-from-reducing-the-lateral-distance-of-sibling/16198373#16198373) (this question has significant overlap with that one) and at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/317. The latter provides a nodeSize argument that I suspect will give a better visual display than arbitrarily shoving the nodes as far apart as possible would.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I ended up modifying the method to accept `nodeSize` as a function, meaning I can calculate the size dynamically depending on the node's depth and number of siblings. Works perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear. You should consider submitting a pull request to the d3 project to incorporate your enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

You can just modify the 'function update(source)', add the follow codes under this function:

```
// Recompute the new height
var levelWidth = [1];
var childCount = function(level, n) {
  if(n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
    if(levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);
    levelWidth[level+1] += n.children.length;
    n.children.forEach(function(d) {
      childCount(level + 1, d);
    });
  }
};
childCount(0, root);  
var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 40; 
tree = tree.size([newHeight, width]);
```

Refer to this like for the detailed question and answer(Superboggly):
[Dynamically resize the d3 tree layout based on number of childnodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103748/dynamically-resize-the-d3-tree-layout-based-on-number-of-childnodes)