# How modify space between node in collapsible tree using d3.js ?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the same problem as this topic : [D3 Tree Layout Separation Between Nodes using NodeSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558649/d3-tree-layout-separation-between-nodes-using-nodesize)

I have tried the solution, but there is another problem, the root is always on the left and when I collapse nodes, they are out of the screen.

the solution is based ond d3.js and on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 but when I set a nodeSize, the root doesn't dynamically move to optimized position.

So How can I have space between my "rect" nodes and a dynamically replace of root node to optimize display ?

Sorry for my bad english !

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 450; });
```

Modify the value 450 to increase/decrease the x axis distance between the nodes