# Get coordinates of clicked on node in d3 tree and centre

Tags: layout, tree, d3.js, click

I have a tree with on click event listeners. I'd like to re-centre my tree on whichever node the user clicked.

How do I get the actual x / y values of a tree node inside the click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the x/y you must translate the nodes back through whatever translation you've already applied:

http://jsfiddle.net/WLaVU shows a working example of what you want.

```
// click event handler 
function click_handler(d)
{
  // these dudes must be smooshed back through the same transform
  var x = xs(d);
  var y = ys(d);

  // normalize for width/height
  var new_x = (-x + (width / 2));
  var new_y = (-y + (height / 2));

  // move the main container g
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + new_x + "," + new_y + ")");
}
```